# Python Kafka producer not able to send json data to a cnosumer

Tags: python, json, apache-kafka

Im trying to send data(**input_data**) in python which looks something like below over kafka.

```
[{
  "stateActionTraffic":"1, S1, 1, A1, 20, 0.65
                        1, S1, 2, A2, 20, 0.65
                        1, S1, 3, A3, 20, 0.65
                        2, S2, 1, A1, 25, 0.65
                        2, S2, 2, A2, 25, 0.65
                        2, S2, 3, A3, 25, 0.65"
   "messageType":"split",
   "Id":1232324334
}]
```

Essentially data type of **input_data** is list

The kafka code that i have tried is following to send in python(3.x) to kafka:

```
import logging
from kafka.errors import KafkaError
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
kafka_brokers=['kafka1-1-stagepf.stage-sin.real.com:9092']
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=kafka_brokers,value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8'), api_version=(1,4,6))
producer.send('topic', input_data)
producer.flush()
```

But on logging I can see that data wasnt sent at all with the following log generated:

```
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=kafka1-1-stagepf.stage-sin.real.com:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('10.14.27.24', 9092)]>: connecting to kafka1-1-stagepf.stage-sin.real.com:9092 [('10.14.27.24', 9092) IPv4]
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=kafka1-1-stagepf.stage-sin.real.com:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('10.14.27.24', 9092)]>: Connection complete.
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=2 host=10.14.26.71:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('10.14.26.71', 9092)]>: connecting to 10.14.26.71:9092 [('10.14.26.71', 9092) IPv4]
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=2 host=10.14.26.71:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('10.14.26.71', 9092)]>: Connection complete.
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=kafka1-1-stagepf.stage-sin.real.com:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('10.14.27.24', 9092)]>: Closing connection. 
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=kafka1-1-stagepf.stage-sin.real.com:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('10.14.27.24', 9092)]>: connecting to kafka1-1-stagepf.stage-sin.real.com:9092 [('10.14.27.24', 9092) IPv4]
WARNING:kafka.conn:SSL connection closed by server during handshake.
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=kafka1-1-stagepf.stage-sin.real.com:9092 <handshake> [IPv4 ('10.14.27.24', 9092)]>: Closing connection. KafkaConnectionError: SSL connection closed by server during handshake
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=kafka1-1-stagepf.stage-sin.real.com:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('10.14.27.24', 9092)]>: connecting to kafka1-1-stagepf.stage-sin.real.com:9092 [('10.14.27.24', 9092) IPv4]
WARNING:kafka.conn:SSL connection closed by server during handshake.
```

So data is not being sent to the kafka domain to its topic as you can see from the log file, where attempts to establish connection and then disconnects. It says **connection complete** but then immediately says **disconnected**. Not sure what is happening here. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are SSL certs self-signed?

Comment: @favoretti - I dont know about that. This is my first time trying to implement kafka producer in python. I wish i could be of more help but this is the only detail that I have at the moment.